# Flutter: build a container with child parameter of type Text

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I would like to make a container that takes Text as parameter. How can I do that?
Here's my code:

```
  class TopBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text text;

  TopBar({
    Key key,
    this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  _TopBarState _TopBarState = _TopBarState();

  @override
  _TopBarState createState() {
    return this._TopBarState = _TopBarState();
  }
}

class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
               // how to add parametrized text here?
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the datatype to String and not Text. You can access the value with widget.text in the widget. You can however keep the datatype as text, but you'll have to pass a Text widget.

Here's the code:

```
  class TopBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  TopBar({
    Key key,
    this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  _TopBarState _TopBarState = _TopBarState();

  @override
  _TopBarState createState() {
    return this._TopBarState = _TopBarState();
  }
}

class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(widget.text),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! just out of curiosity, how would I pass a Text widget instead of String?

Comment: @Heisenberg change the parameter type back to Text and then you can just type `yourParameterName` under children in the Row

Comment: That didn't work for me, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Heisenberg, Example: TopBar(text:Text("content here"),). It can be done like this.